# Should we, or when should we use exception to the number of significant figures?

Tags: significant-figures

For example, if we need an answer that is precise to 4 significant figures. Or, let's say it is the standard procedure to use 4 significant figures in a department in a company.

Say, if the probability of failure is `0.02441%`, if we write it as the probability of success, then it is `99.98%`. Now both are 4 significant figures, but the `0.02441%` definitely is more informative than the `99.98%`. For example, we can say `99.98%`. Now is it `99.975%` or is it `99.98499%`? Both become `99.98%` but the former gives a failure rate of `0.025%` and the latter gives `0.01501%`, and they differ a lot by percentage (`0.01501 x 166% = 0.025`), and it is far less information than what the number `0.02441%` can provide.

In fact, if department A states it as 99.98% success, then department B can later quote that its failure rate is 0.02% (vs 0.02441%), reducing the failure rate by 20%, "scientifically and mathematically" correct.

So shouldn't there be an exception in this case, but is there a rule that says there should be an exception, and how many significant numbers should be provided -- and is there also a rule?

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, if you want to know $1-x$ to four significant figures, you may need to know $x$ to a lot more than four significant figures if $x$ is close to 1.

So if a company has a rule that means they only store 4 significant digits of any number, they also have to outlaw subtracting numbers that are close to each other, or accept that such numbers will be far less accurate than 4 significant digits.